# Why am I getting “Validation failed” on a save with Doctrine on Symfony 1.4?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I have the following error while importing some data via Doctrine :

```
value1:19.022542
value2:497.795
value3:9466.541667
Caught exception: Validation failed in class DataPerDay

  27 fields had validation errors:

    * 1 validator failed on value1 (type)
    * 1 validator failed on value2 (type)
    * 1 validator failed on value3 (type)
```

I don't understand this validation error !!
The fields **are** of type float, what could be going on here ?

schema.yml :

```
DataPerDay:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: xp_data_per_day
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    inverter_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    (...)
    value1:
      type: float
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    (...)
```

Weirder still, I have the error on the production environnent, not on localhost :(

EDIT : in BaseDataPerDayFormFilter.class.php, the validators are :

```
'value1'      => new sfValidatorSchemaFilter('text', new sfValidatorNumber(array('required' => false))),
```

Is this ok ?

Comment: cleard the cache? did you set custom validation rules somewhere? How do you import the data?

Comment: I'm in /lib/tasks; the cache is not sent by subversion

Comment: Hum from a xml file. foreach($xml->children()); $data->value1 = $value; $data->save()

Comment: The mysql server version is different, too. Could that explain the different results ?

Comment: I don't think so, because the validation has nothing to do with the mysql server. Make sure you ran `symfony cc`, otherwise I don't have any idea what the problem is.

Comment: Oh, there's another difference between local and prod : the environment ! Maybe I have a weird setting in databases.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was not in schema.yml, but in **databases.yml** :

```
prod:
  doctrine:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      profiler: false
      dsn: 'mysql:host=xxx.net;dbname=xxx'
      port: 3306
      username: xxx
      password: xxx
      encoding: UTF8
      attributes:
        quote_identifier: false
        use_native_enum: false
        idxname_format: %s_idx
        seqname_format: %s_seq
        tblname_format: %s
        validate: all
```

I don't know where this "`validate: all`" came from, but it was what was creating those errors.